# How to convert my count value to enum as output?

Tags: c++11, enums, bit-manipulation

This is a sample snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum class status{
CONNECTED,
NOT_CONNECTED
};

int main(){

std::string x;
std::cout<<"Enter a binary string = ";
std::getline(std::cin,x);
int count = 0;
for (int i=0;i < x.size() ; i++){
    if(x[i] & 1)
        ++count;
}

 std::cout<<"count = " <<count <<std::endl;
 return count;
}
```

I want to use the value of my count to compare and result out the enum type as an output.
That is I want to do:

```
//pseudo: 
if(count == 1 ) output state_CONNECTED;
elseif(count > 1) output state_DISCONNECTED;
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Yes you are right. @skypjack

Comment: @skypjack kindly suggest me a way

Comment: Works great @skypjack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::underlying_type_t` to do that:

```
if(count == 1) {
    std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<status>>(status::CONNECTED) << std::endl;
} else if(count > 1) {
    std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<status>>(status::NOT_CONNECTED) << std::endl;
}
```

In C++11 it becomes:

```
if(count == 1) {
    std::cout << static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<status>::type>(status::CONNECTED) << std::endl;
} else if(count > 1) {
    std::cout << static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<status>::type>(status::NOT_CONNECTED) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks @skypjack